# Problem Compiling c++ Code With SLD2 From VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, sdl-2

I'm just getting started with c++ and I can't seem to get c++ to compile with SDL2. I am using VS code and MinGW. I have copied the include files from the SDL2 download and the lib files into their respective folders in the mingw64 folder (as according to step 1-5 of this - https://www.caveofprogramming.com/c-for-complete-beginners/setting-up-sdl-windows.html). The code the vs code runs when I "run build task" is below.

`C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\lucya\Downloads\c++\programmingcave\cave.cpp -o C:\Users\lucya\Downloads\c++\programmingcave\cave.exe`

I am trying to build some basic code I copy and pasted which is below.

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Start SDL2
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
 
    // Create a Window in the middle of the screen
    SDL_Window *window = 0;
 
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              640, 480,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
 
    // Delay so that we can see the window appear
    SDL_Delay(2000);
 
    // Cleanup and Quit
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
 
    return 0;
}
```

However, This is what comes up when I "run build task":

```
Starting build...
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\lucya\Downloads\c++\programmingcave\cave.cpp -o C:\Users\lucya\Downloads\c++\programmingcave\cave.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lucya\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOYoA98.o:C:/Users/lucya/Downloads/c++/programmingcave/cave.cpp:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lucya\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOYoA98.o: in function `main':
C:/Users/lucya/Downloads/c++/programmingcave/cave.cpp:11: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/lucya/Downloads/c++/programmingcave/cave.cpp:18: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/lucya/Downloads/c++/programmingcave/cave.cpp:21: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/lucya/Downloads/c++/programmingcave/cave.cpp:22: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

Does anyone know what my error is or how to fix it? If you need any other information please just ask! I have spent 2 days trying to get this to work so any help is useful.

Thanks!

Comment: ***Does anyone know what my error is or how to fix it?*** Does not look like you are linking to the sdl libraries. ***C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\lucya\Downloads\c++\programmingcave\cave.cpp -o C:\Users\lucya\Downloads\c++\programmingcave\cave.exe*** should have a `-L` to set the library folder and `-l`  for each library to link.

Comment: How do I change that in vs code?

Comment: Edit your tasks.json

Comment: @drescherjm thank you so much for this help!!! Finally after 2 days now it works!